# Why might this device have both 原稿面上向き and 送信面上向き as equivalents of "face up"?

Tags: words

Recently, I found the following instructions on a multifunction printer/scanner/copier/faxer:

[image: instructions on a multifunction printer/scanner/copier/faxer device]

Curiously, there are two lines in Japanese (as opposed to just one in each of the other languages): 原稿面上向き and 送信面上向き. I guess these would be equivalent to "front of the page facing up" and "the side you want to send facing up" (for faxing), but this appears to be redundant. To me, it seems that 原稿面 would subsume 送信面.

Is this just an artefact of how this particular sign was translated, or would devices manufactured for sale in Japan also feature two separate instructions where an English-language device would just have "face up"? If the latter, why? (e.g. might there be some sort of distinction between 原稿面 and 送信面 in Japanese that I'm not aware of?)

Comment: It looks like they wanted both Chinese and Japanese and by whatever process ended up with Japanese twice.

Comment: @Earthliŋ I suspected this might be the case. Would you (or someone) happen to know how "face up" in this context would typically be translated into Chinese?

Comment: I speak no word of Chinese, but it seems that "The original face up" might be something like 原稿面**向上**. (I found it in a Chinese printer manual.) Hopefully some Chinese speaker will stumble across this.

Comment: (I have posted a related question to Chinese.SE: http://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/14034/)

Answer (score 4):

My opinion:

原稿面上向き - for making copies

送信面上向き - for sending faxes

I think, this is the Japanese specific they try to explain things as much as possible, so they introduced both explanations.